# Ninject: Is it possible to have parent object in SingletonScope and child in TransientScope?

Tags: c#, architecture, ninject

I have been racking my brain on and off with this for a few weeks now... What I currenlty have is this:

- A bunch of `*Service` classes
- All of these depend on different `*Repository` classes that access database via EF
- To allow Unit Testing a derivate of `DbContext` is injected into repositories. (so I can not use `using` to dispose of the contexts)

To correctly dispose of the EF contexts that are injected I could run my dependency tree in `InRequestScope()` or in a simple custom scope - `InScope(c => new object())` on the top level and in `InParentScope()` on all other levels.

Both of these approaches would create and dispose a lot of objects during each request. In addition we are talking about a single page application so that 95% of the queries (50 or so) will be executed during 2 requests so `InRequestScope()` seems not to be a good idea. Also the `*Service` classes hold no state and thus could be `InSingletonScope()` and would minimize the amount of object creation.

**The Question**

Is it possible to have parent `*Service` and `*Repository` classes in `InSingletonScope()` and somehow inject EF `DbContext` in a scope that will return a new instance each time it is accessed and will honor `IDisposable` using NInject?

I know that dependencies are injected while objects are created but could this still be somehow managed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's not possible.  If you think about it, you should understand why.

A singleton object will exist for the lifetime of the application.  An InRequestScope object lives for the lifetime of a request.  Since your singleton repository will live forever, and it will hold a reference to your DbContext (because it's a dependency), that means the dbcontext cannot be garbage collected without your repository having some mechanism to release it.

Even if you did supply such a mechanism, you'd have to have another mechanism to re-acquire a new instance on the next request, because a new singleton repository will not be created (and thus it's constructor will not be called, and thus it's dependencies will not be resolved, and thus it will not be able know about the new dbcontext).

So, in effect, making an InRequestScope object a dependency of a singleton object would effectively make the InRequestScope object a singleton, or else the object will be disposed out from under the singleton and that could be bad..

Also, I beg to differ with you on the fact that your repositories *DO* have state.  The state is the DbContext itself.  Since a Singleton is an application wide static instance, you give the same instance to all users using your app, which would mean it would also give the same DbContext, which is a huge no-no, since your users would stomp all over each others DbContext state.

Your services are also, likewise, stateful because they have repositories, which as I've just pointed out have DbContexts, which are stateful.

What you want to do is simply make your Services, repositories, and DbContexts all InRequestScope.

I fail to understand why this approach would "create lots of objects during each request".  The whole point is that it only creates one instance of each object type per request.

Comment: The problem of state enters the equation only when I start to inject the context. If my repositories would simply new up a context in a using block then there would not be a state issue. And I did figure out that via constructor injection a singleton would get what ever dependencies it needs once and only once. I was hoping/dreaming that this kind of scenario would be possible using properties and call interception not being too familiar with Ninject. But I guess it is out of the question :)

Comment: @juhan_h - Well, you can of course manually force injection of properties, but that doesn't solve the state issue because properties are also stateful.  Nor would using interception, since you would at best be able to resolve a new context when a method was called, but would still have issues of concurrency in a multi-user environment with singleton state. Singletons are shared application-wide, not request-wide or even user-wide.  Any state you change in a singleton affects every user of the app

Comment: @juhan_h - but you're really overthinking this... and over-optimizing.  Just make the repositories InRequestScope() and be done with it.. That's what they're there for.

Comment: You are correct that properties would indeend bring a host of concurrency issues. And I am converting it to InRequestScope() as I am typing this. Thaks for your time and for widening my horizons.

Comment: @juhan_h - One option, if your repositories and services are truly stateless, is to not use dependency injection for them at all, but rather make them static classes that you call, passing the dbcontext to the method.  Then you just inject the dbcontext into whatever parent object calls into the service.

Comment: An alternative approach could be to inject a DbContextFactory into the repositories. The methods in the repositories would get the dbContext from the factory and the factory would be made to return dbContexts that are InRequestScope. This way you can have the services and repositories InSingletonScope without leaking state between concurrent requests. I still prefer having it all InRequestScope though, it's simpler to reason about.