# What is the best way to inject repositories into an ASP.NET controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ninject

We have a project written in ASP.NET MVC and we use NInject to inject the repositories into the controllers. Currently we are using properties and the Inject-attribute to inject the repositories, which works well enough:

```
[Inject]
public IMyRepository MyRepos {get;set;}
```

An alternative way of injecting would be to do it "manually" using the `NInjectServiceLocator`:

```
var myRepos = NInjectServiceLocatorInstance.Resolve<IMyRepository>();
```

Now I was wondering about the following: the first method requires all repositories to be listed at the top (not necessarily at the top of course, but it's the most logical place) of a controller. Whenever a request is made, NInject instantiates each and every repository. This happens regardless of whether all of the repositories are actually needed inside a specific Action.

With the second method you can more precisely control which repositories are actually necessary and thus this might save some overhead when the controller is created. But you probably also have to include code to retrieve the same repository in multiple places.

So which one would be better? Is it better to just have a bunch of repository-properties or is it better to resolve the repositories which are actually necessary for a specific action when and where you need them? Is there a performance penalty involved for injecting "useless" repositories? Are there (even ;-) better solutions out there?

Comment: Calling `NInjectServiceLocatorInstance.Resolve` is a pattern called Service Locator. There has been written a lot about this here on Stackoverflow and on the internet (for instance this is a [famous article](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/)).

Comment: @Steven: I know about the pattern and that it also has its pros and cons. As I said, using a service locator might still not be the best solution, but would it be better than property- or constructor-injection in this case?

Comment: This is the order in which you should do injection: Constructor injection, property injection, factories, method injection, service locator. Only select the next option if the previous is not an appropriate.

Comment: @Steven Define "appropriate". Is it better to define five repositories in a constructor when a specific action only uses one? Or is better (maybe from the point-of-view of performance, maybe from the point-of-view of readability) to use the service locator and ask NInject for the desired repository where it's actually necessary?

Comment: "Appropriate" means: if you can do it, you should do it! Injecting services that are not always used at runtime should not be a problem, since object graph construction should be really fast (which means: don't do anything in your constructors besides storing references). If you inject more than 5 dependencies, you are probably violating the Single Responsibility Principle. This will result in maintainance problems. If you need to delay the creation of a type, you can't use ctor and prop injection, but you shouldn't use service locator, since you can use a factory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Constructor Injection` should be your default choice when using DI.

You should ask yourself if the controller is really dependent on that specific class to work at all.

Maybe `Method injection` could also be a solution for specific scenario's, if you have only specific methods that needs dependencies.

I've never used `Property Injection` but Mark Seeman describes it in his book ([Dependency Injection in .NET](http://www.manning.com/seemann/)):

> PROPERTY INJECTION should only be used when the class you’re developing has a good
>   LOCAL DEFAULT and you still want to enable callers to provide different implementations
>   of the class’s DEPENDENCY.
>
> PROPERTY INJECTION is best used when the DEPENDENCY is optional.
>
> NOTE There’s some controversy around the issue of whether PROPERTY INJECTION
>   indicates an optional DEPENDENCY. As a general API design principle, I
>   consider properties to be optional because you can easily forget to assign
>   them and the compiler doesn’t complain. If you accept this principle in the
>   general case, you must also accept it in the special case of DI. 4

A local default is described as:

> A default implementation of an ABSTRACTION that’s defined in the same assembly as
>   the consumer.

Unless you're building an API I would suggest not to use Property Injection

> Whenever a request is made, NInject instantiates each and every repository. This happens regardless of whether all of the repositories are actually needed inside a specific Action.

I don't think you should worry to much about the performance when using constructor injection

Comment: The remarks doe make sense to me, but I'm wondering if in this case it might actually make the code more readable if you only ask for the necessary repositories to be injected where they are actually needed and not in a constructor or as a property.

Comment: I don't think readable code is based on how you implement DI, DI is only a way to create loose coupling in your application so your code is more maintainable. If implemented the right way

Comment: Note the Ninject wiki explicitly states property injection as descibed in Mark Seeman's book (Dependency Injection in .net) is not supported.

Answer (score 3):

I prefer constructor injection:

```
private readonly IMyRepository _repository;

public MyController(IMyRepository repository)
{
    _repository = repository;
}
```

- All your dependencies are listed in one operation
- Your controller does not need to know anything about NInject
- You can unit-test your controller without NInjects involvment by stubbing interfaces straight to the constructor
- Controller has a cleaner code

NInject or any other DI framework will do the work behind the scenes and leave you concentrating on the actual problem, not DI.

Comment: This has the same drawback as with the properties I'm using now. The only difference is that now all of the repositories need to be in the constructor.

Comment: Indeed it does but by managing your repositories scope (InRequestScope) for instance they will be created only once per request. In my opinion the cleanlyness and maintainability of code trumps over unnecessary object creation. If your repositories are actually pure repositories then the object creations overhead will be very small. I struggled with same kind of problem (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18203401/ninject-is-it-possible-to-have-parent-object-in-singletonscope-and-child-in-tra) and decided this was a micro-optimization.

Comment: All injections are, of course, in request scope. And you might be right that this is a micro-optimization in terms of performance at leats. But it might actually make the code more readable as the repositories are only injected where they are actually needed.

Comment: constructor injection it will be always the cleanest way inject dependencies to me property injector are somewhat obscure if you're not the developer when using a property set injection is very difficult to know what dependencies are required and what are not!

Answer (score 0):

By far my favorite method is:

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    public IMyRepository MyRepos {get;set;}

    public MyController(IMyRepository repo)
    {
        MyRepos = repo;
    }
}
```

So you can use a NuGet package, such as Ninject.MVC3 (or MVC4) which has specific support for including the Ninject kernel inside the MVC's own IoC classes

https://github.com/ninject/ninject.web.mvc/wiki/MVC3

Once you have Ninject hooks in, you can let it do the work of injection instances into the  controller's constructor, which I think is a lot cleaner.

EDIT:

Ahh, OK. Having read your question a bit more thoroughly, I see where you're going with this. In short, if you want to pick and choose which repo classes are instansiated then you will need to manually call, for example:

`var myRepos = NInjectServiceLocatorInstance.Resolve<IMyRepository>();`

You cannot configure Ninject (or any other IoC AFAIK) to selectively create object instances based on the currently execute method. That level of granularity is a real edge case I feel, which may be solvable by writing your own controller factory class, but that would be overkill.

Comment: This has the same drawback as with the properties I'm using now. The only difference is that now all of the repositories need to be in the constructor.